# SQL dump loads with Error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

## **Looks like this issue is just the wrong version of MySQL, need to go to 5.5**

So I have a backup of an offsite source SQL database.  I am not sure how they are preforming the data dump but I am trying to find out.  This database needs to be imported on the new computer.  Every time I try to run the commands below I get the error (at the bottom of the post).  I want to be able to load this data with out an error.  What do I need to do to get the data to load correctly?  So far none of the tables load at all from the dump.

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

I get the error 1064.  I also tried to load this in MySQL with

```
source \home\user\Desktop\test.sql;
```

- MySQL v12.22 Distrib 4.0.26-nt-max, for Win32 (ia32)
- Protocol
  version, 10
- Client characterset, latin1
- Server characterset, latin1
- Windows XP SP3
- InnoDB is coming up at the type in show create table *tablename*;

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1' at line 1

when trying to add a different table

> ERROR 1074: Too big column length for column 'City' .  Use BLOB instead

ok I kept messing with this, the following code works when I remove, DEFAULT CHATSET=latin1

```
CREATE TABLE `aaaa` (`MYID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Your version information is missing bit - what does `SELECT VERSION()` show? Do you know which SQL is generating those error. The 1074 error looks odd. A column too big for a city name - I don't know of any cities having 30 character names let alone 64k names. Do you know what source database version?

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the original text that got the error!  It sounds like you had the `DEFAULT CHARSET` clause in the wrong spot.

Comment: @RickJames It is probably in the right spot.  ended up finding out it is an error caused by having the incorrect version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In the commandline tool, use forwardslash, not backslash, for path delimiters:

```
source /home/user/Desktop/test.sql;
```